# How can using a VPN increase network speed?

Tags: vpn, proxy

There are lots of guides online which suggest that using a VPN or proxy will gain better speed or 'free internet' however this seems unlikely.

If my ISP is performing packet shaping on my connection. How does using a VPN or proxy speed up my internet connection?

Is this just a trick or is it actually a way around traffic restrictions?

Comment: Not sure where you got this information, but you *can't* increase the speed if your ISP is limiting it. Although you can fool people by demonstrating fake videos for some reasons: 1- To show off 2- To let them download a rat (hack them) 3- To win some money by protecting the link with some ads.

Comment: VPNs can be used to avoid ISP traffic shaping by hiding your traffic characteristics from your ISP. I've never knowingly been a victim of traffic shaping though, so I have no direct experience in this area.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV just google it - ISP hacks, 3g tricks, airtel hacks, vodafone proxy tricks etc

Comment: What's probably happening is the VPN is used to trick the ISP's packet shaper. The ISP may be throttling things like a youtube video and music stream (which is UDP), but with a VPN a packetshaper could be tricked.

With that said, I don't think this is a very good question for Sec.SE

Comment: ok close this question, @HamZaDzCyberDeV you are right ????

Comment: @MarkEvans I've no idea, I used to surf on the net and found articles/videos on "how to speed up my connection" but they were almost all fake. So basically I'm waiting for someone who knows better to shed some light on the topic.

Answer (score 2):

This is mainly to evade traffic shapers. For instance torrent traffic will get lower priority than for instance VOIP or SSH. VPNs are used to hide that traffic and to evade traffic shaping or even evade blocking. Honestly I haven't seen a lot of VPNs that allow massive speeds. Are ISPs fools? Some are but some just cant be bothered because the amount of users using a VPN to evade these shapers are too few to have a real impact on their network. If they did have an pact they probably would start blocking these. VPN providers as well.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely way would be if the VPN implemented end-to-end compression,
but it could also improve performance by managing packet size and retransmission
policies.  For example, small packets could be bundled into bigger packets
before transmission, reducing overhead.